# How to filter specific text from the JSON response array using typescript?

Tags: typescript, request-promise

Want to filter some specific text from following rest response

My response is similar to

```
 [ { time: '03:45:55',
   absolute_time: '2019-07-17T03:45:55Z',
   log:
    '/home/ec2-user/soapui-report/2019-07-17/154513482/Project Report.pdf',
   level: 'NORMAL',
   user: 'ec2-user',
   stepctx: '1',
   node: 'QA-Server-jmeter' },
 { time: '03:45:55',
   absolute_time: '2019-07-17T03:45:55Z',
   log:
    'Login:https://training-labs.com/\\nUsername : michelle@test.com.test ',
   level: 'NORMAL',
   user: 'ec2-user',
   stepctx: '1',
   node: 'QA-Server-jmeter' },
 { time: '03:45:55',
   absolute_time: '2019-07-17T03:45:55Z',
   log: '221 2.0.0 Bye',
   level: 'ERROR',
   user: 'ec2-user',
   stepctx: '1',
   node: 'QA-Server-jmeter' } ]
```

I want to get the value of 'Username' from the JSON response. That is 'michelle@test.com.test'. I am using TypeScripts. Help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The value of 'Username' from the JSON response? but the username is not there rite?

Comment: Hi @ChandanYS , 'nUsername : michelle@test.com.test' will be like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you expect *Username* to appear in the log attribute only, one possible solution could look as follows. This creates a `string array` of all usernames found in your response.

```
const label = 'Username :';
const usernames = response
    .map(r => r.log)
    .filter(log => log.includes(label))
    .map(log => log.split(label).splice(-1)[0])
    .map(user => user.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a string and return everything that matches:

```
JSON.stringify(response)
.match(/(?<=Username : )(.*@.*)(?= )/)
```

The regex can be improved but i think you geht the idea.